# How can I make a flexbox container scale my page?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to make a flexbox container the same size as the window?

Comment: What about: `width: 100%;` or `width: 100vw;`?

Comment: seems that the height is still the height of the elements in the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some element, flex or not to be the same size as your window, then you are looking for viewport units, wich are **vh** and **vw**.
If you want to achieve the height of the window, you want `height: 100vh;`, and if you want the width of the window, you want `width: 100vw;`
You can also use bouth.

Answer (score 0):

Use the snippet below. This will fit the element to the size of the entire page.

```css
.flexbox-container {
  background-color:blue; // just to show element filling page.
  position:fixed !important;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make flexbox container the same size as the window add the below given properties to the flexbox container :

```
height:100vh;
width:100%;
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.flexdiv{
height:100vh;
width:100%;
background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexdiv"></div>
```